# Pulling info from ansible facts into an inventory format

Tags: ansible

In order to make use of ansible patterns which seems to offer the most command line flexbility  I would like to generate inventory based on project name,  distro,  architecture.  The first one I can do with ansible_inventory but gathering the facts for distro and arch in an inventory format I'm not so clear

So more specifically I would like to create an inventory file so that the format looks like this

```
rehdat8:
   hosts:
      hosta: {}
      hostb: {}

ubuntu16:
   hosts:
      hostc: {}

x86_64:
   hosts:
      hosta: {}
      hostc: {}

ppc64:
   hosts:
      hostb: {}
```

I believe the way I can do this is start off with a basic inventory list

```
hosta
hostb
hostc
hostd
```

and run an inventory generation playbook which prints a fact when it matches
eg.

```
- debug:
        msg: "{{ ansible_architecture }}"
        when:  ansible_architecture  == 'ppc64'
```

Unfortunately, I get syntax errors with the when but I can print the msg if the when statement is commented. Here's the error I see when using the when condition

**fatal: [hosta]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Invalid options for debug: when"}**

Comment: Perfect.   That was the fix - thanks very much

Answer (score 5):

Indention is wrong

```
- debug:
        msg: "{{ ansible_architecture }}"
  when:  ansible_architecture  == 'ppc64'
```